# Soundcloud API key

Tags: api, soundcloud, api-key

When I create an app on Soundcloud I get a Client ID and Client Secret. Within the app's settings screen I can't find and API key.

The javascript api asks for a API key, where do i get the key?

Comment: Are you following the instructions on this page? http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript If so you should find that it's possible to use the JS SDK with the client ID supplied by SoundCloud.

Answer (score 1):

**Client ID** is what they mean by API key.

If you use their JavaScript SDK, you would call this script to set it up:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID", // API key
    redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html",
});
```

Once configured, you can use the SDK methods without having to provide `client_id` again:

```
SC.get("/tracks", {q: "hello"}, function(tracks){
    // do something with the result tracks
});
```

If you inspect the request (e.g. with Firebug), you may see your `client_id` in the requested URL:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=hello&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```